# Getting current class in method call

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class A:
    def x ( self ):
        print( self.__class__ )

class B ( A ):
    pass

b = B()
b.x()
```

In the above situation, is there any way for the method `x` to get a reference to class `A` instead of `B`? Of course simply writing `print( A )` is not allowed, as I want to add some functionality with a decorator that needs the class `A` (and as I can't pass A itself to the decorator directly, as the class doesn't exist yet at that point).

Comment: Every time I wanted to do this I ended up realizing that I messed up the class design or just wanted a Mixin ... maybe your problem is the same.

Comment: why you need this? may be that should have been the question.

Comment: Well, I'm quite sure that I wouldn't need this; basically I wanted a method decorator that automatically calls the method of the super class. However to use the correct base class in the super call, I need a reference to the *current* object. I have solved it now however by recycling one of my previous (failed) approaches and fixed it with ideas from Alex' answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have `super`-calls involved (or more generally subclasses that override `x` and call directly to `A.x(self)` as part of their override's implementation), looking for the first item in `type(self).mro()` that has an `x` attribute would work --

```
next(c for c in type(self).mro() if hasattr(c, 'x'))
```

If you do need to cover for `super`-calls, it's harder -- unless you happen to know that no **super**-class of `A` defines an `x` attribute (and of course it's easier to know about your superclasses than your subclasses, though multiple inheritance does complicate it;-) in which case you only need the *last* appropriate item of the `mro` instead of the first one.

Comment: While this wasn't really what I needed, it gave me the needed hint to solve my problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use name mangling to associate the class a method is defined in with a method:

```
def set_defining_class(cls):
    setattr(cls, '_%s__defining_class' % (cls.__name__,), cls)
    return cls

@set_defining_class
class A(object):
    def x (self):
        print(self.__defining_class)

@set_defining_class
class B ( A ):
    pass


b = B()
b.x()
```

Done here with a class decorator, but you could do it by hand, or in a metaclass too.

Comment: That's actually a nice way of storing such information, thanks!